# Do browsers block POST requests if POST isn’t in the Access-Control-Allow-Methods value of the preflight OPTIONS response?

Tags: post, cors, preflight

I think I understand CORS pretty well, but I'm still a bit puzzled about the browser's behavior when it comes to the preflight requests.

Let's say the browser issues this preflight request:

```http
OPTIONS http://myserver.local:7000/api/order/4 HTTP/1.1
Host: myserver.local:7000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-my-custom-header
Origin: http://localhost:5000
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: http://localhost:5000/
```

and my API returns:

```http
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Date: Wed, 09 Mar 2022 12:52:50 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-my-custom-header
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5000
Vary: Origin
```

Note that the server allows methods `PUT` and `DELETE` in the response to the preflight request, but not `POST`, which is the method of the actual CORS request.

Should the browser not block this request due to the mismatch between the actual request's method and the methods listed in the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header? Or is it enough that the server respond with a `20x` status code for the browser to accept the preflight and then send the actual request?

My assumptions was that the browser would compare the allow-methods and block the request if the requested method did no match... Am I missing something?

Comment: An interesting question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### TL;DR

No, the browser doesn't require the server to explicitly allow the `POST` method, because the latter, as a so-called [*CORS-safelisted method*](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-method), gets a free pass.

---

### More details

#### What the spec says

The answer, as always, lies in the Fetch standard ([section 4.8](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-fetch)), which specifies how CORS works:

> 1. Let *methods* be the result of extracting header list values given `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and *response*’s header list.

And further down:

> 5. If request’s method is not in *methods*, ***request*’s method is not a CORS-safelisted method**, and request’s credentials mode is `"include"` or *methods* does not contain `*`, then return a network error.

(my emphasis)

What is a *CORS-safelisted method*? The term is defined in [section 2.2.1](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#methods):

> A CORS-safelisted method is a method that is `GET`, `HEAD`, or `POST`.

#### Interpretation

If the method of the CORS request is one of `GET`, `HEAD`, or `POST`, the browser doesn't require the server to explicitly list that method in the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header for CORS preflight to succeed.

#### Experiment

I've found [Jake Archibald](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake)'s [CORS playground](https://jakearchibald.com/2021/cors/playground/) useful for testing my (mis)understanding of CORS. Running [this particular instance](https://jakearchibald.com/2021/cors/playground/?prefillForm=1&requestMethod=POST&requestUseCORS=1&preflightStatus=204&preflightAllowOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fjakearchibald.com&preflightAllowMethods=PUT%2CDELETE&preflightAllowHeaders=x-my-custom-header&responseStatus=200&responseAllowOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fjakearchibald.com&requestHeaderName=x-my-custom-header&requestHeaderValue=foo) in your browser may convince you that the `POST` method doesn't need to be explicitly allowed for CORS preflight to succeed.

Comment: awesome explanation! Thanks!