# Enable CORS just for GET Requests in ASP NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors

I am trying to enable `CORS` just for `GET` requests, but I seem to be struggling. From reading the documentation, I understand that this should be achievable by adding the `WithMethods` method but doesn't seem working to me. Rather, I do not hit a CORS error, even when `fetch`ing via `POST`.

Below is my code

**(Note that I am adding 2 `UseCors` just to demonstrate that I have tried 2 overloads, both to no avail, both return fine with `POST`).**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options=>{
    options.AddPolicy("customPolicy",policy=>{
        policy.WithOrigins("https://customsite.com").WithMethods("GET");
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors("customPolicy");

app.UseCors(options=>{
    options.WithOrigins("https://customsite.com").WithMethods("GET");
});

app.MapPost("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: How do you access your page/api? What "cors error" do you expect to get?

Comment: I am accessing it from the chrome console when on a different URL via FETCH. I expect to get something similar to this "Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:7173/' from origin " etc

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71409753/do-browsers-block-post-requests-if-post-isn-t-in-the-access-control-allow-method

Comment: @YossiSternlicht I'm curious about your use case... In particular, the request that would be generated in your example is _simple_ (i.e. not be preflighted). Therefore, there would be no opportunity to fail the CORS check at preflight. Would it not be easier for you to activate CORS on the `GET` endpoint, and not on the `HEAD` and `POST` endpoints?

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/1517

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicybuilder.withmethods?view=aspnetcore-6.0 are not so clear but I arrived at the answer from Andrew Locks book ASP NET CORE in Action 2e (page 597).

The `WithMethods` method is permissive, not restrictive. By default, the simple headers (such as `GET`, `HEAD` and `POST` as in our example) are allowed by default, (and I would not know how to disable one of them). But other method types, such as `PUT` would fail in the example provided. Only by adding the correct name in the method, such as `WithMethods("PUT")` will allow the request to participate in `CORS`.