# CORS only allowing GET requests .NET/Angular

Tags: .net, angular, cors, backend

I have a service class in Angular where I've placed my API calls:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { RectangleCoordinates } from "../models/interfaces/RectangleCoordinates";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class RectangleService {
  readonly RECTANGLE_API = "https://localhost:7192/api/Rectangle";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getRectangleCoordinates(): Observable<RectangleCoordinates> {
    return this.http.get<RectangleCoordinates>(this.RECTANGLE_API);
  }

  updateRectangleCoordinates(rectangleCoords: RectangleCoordinates) {
    this.http.put(this.RECTANGLE_API, rectangleCoords).subscribe();
  }
}
```

In my ASP.NET 6 Web API backend I have my program.cs file set up to allow CORS like this:

```
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                        policy =>
                        {
                            policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
                        });
});

....

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```

The GET request works wonderfully, but the PUT request gives me this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:7192/api/Rectangle' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.

Why could this be? It seems I have enabled CORS properly and why only for GET requests?

Comment: Not sure why, but Fixed by adding this:

policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
.AllowAnyMethod()
.AllowAnyHeader();

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable CORS just for GET Requests in ASP NET 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74057378/enable-cors-just-for-get-requests-in-asp-net-6)

Comment: @possum tried i, but it doesn't work, check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but only works with this:

```
policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
.AllowAnyMethod()
.AllowAnyHeader();
```

Comment: Anyone coming across this in the future, this allows any origin and is not restrictive to the sites that can access it.  This may be a security risk.

Answer (score -1):

Check this approach.

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy => policy.AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200"));
});
```

then call it like this:

```
app.UseCors();
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).