# Unexpected CORS Behavior: POST Request Succeeds Despite 'GET' Only in Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Tags: javascript, express, browser, cors, fetch-api

I am currently teaching a course on web development where I demonstrate the use of Express.js along with the 'cors' middleware. I've encountered a strange behavior that contradicts my understanding of CORS.

Here's my server setup:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.use(
 cors({
   origin: "http://127.0.0.1:5500",
   methods: ["GET"],
 })
);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
console.log("do something in get req");
res.send("Hello from server");
});

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
console.log("do something in post req");
res.send("Hello from server post");
});

app.put("/", (req, res) => {
console.log("do something in put req");
res.send("Hello from server put");
});

app.listen(8181, () => {
console.log("Server is listening on port 8181");
});
```

I have a client-side fetch call:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8181/", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2",
  }),
})
.then((res) => res.text())
.then((data) => console.log(data))
.catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Although the CORS settings on the server are configured to only accept GET requests from the origin "http://127.0.0.1:5500", the POST request from the client-side completes successfully and the response data is successfully logged on the browser console.

I was expecting the POST request to be blocked by the browser due to the CORS policy. However, this is not the case. The preflight request confirms that the Access-Control-Allow-Methods header only contains the method 'GET', as per my server configuration. Therefore, I expected the browser to block any non-GET request, but this does not seem to happen.

I've tested this on both Chrome and Edge browsers, ensuring to clear the cache with a hard refresh (Ctrl + F5), and in both cases, the POST request goes through successfully.

[images from the dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVjIn.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do browsers block POST requests if POST isn’t in the Access-Control-Allow-Methods value of the preflight OPTIONS response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71409753/do-browsers-block-post-requests-if-post-isn-t-in-the-access-control-allow-method)