# AspNetCore CORS GraphQL POST methods are not blocked

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http, graphql, cors

I have the following Program.cs

```
using Business;
using Foo.Application.Core;
using Foo.Application.Core.Identity;
using Foo.Infrastructure.Core;
using Foo.Presentation.Core;
using HotChocolate.Data;
using Oakton;
using dotenv.net;
using NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware.Middleware;
using Serilog;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// --- LOAD CONFIG START
DotEnv.Load(new DotEnvOptions(envFilePaths: new[] { ".env", $"{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.env" }));
builder.Configuration
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true )
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
// --- LOAD CONFIG END

// --- LOGGER START
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
    .CreateLogger();
builder.Host.UseSerilog(logger);
// --- LOGGER END

builder.Host.ApplyOaktonExtensions();

var services = builder.Services;

// --- DI START 
services.AddCoreInfrastructure(builder.Configuration)
  .AddCoreApplication(builder.Configuration)
  .AddCorePresentation(builder.Configuration)
  .AddBusiness(builder.Configuration);
services.AddScoped<ICurrentUserService, CurrentUserServiceMock>();
// --- DI END 

// --- CORS START
var corsPolicy = "AllowOrigin";
var cors = builder.Configuration.GetSection($"Cors:{corsPolicy}");
var corsOrigins = cors.GetSection("Origins").Get<string[]>() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cors:{corsPolicy}:Origins was not provided");
var corsMethods = cors.GetSection("Methods").Get<string[]>() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cors:{corsPolicy}:Methods was not provided");
var corsHeaders = cors.GetSection("Headers").Get<string[]>() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cors:{corsPolicy}:Headers was not provided");

services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(corsPolicy, policyBuilder =>
    {
        policyBuilder.WithOrigins(corsOrigins).WithMethods(corsMethods).WithHeaders(corsHeaders);
    });
});
// --- CORS END

// --- MEDIATR START
services.AddMediatR(options =>
{
    options.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(
        typeof(Program).Assembly,
        typeof(BusinessDependencyInjection).Assembly);
});
// --- MEDIATR END

// --- HOT CHOCOLATE - MARTEN START
builder.Services
    .AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddTypes()
    .AddMartenFiltering()
    .AddMartenSorting();
// --- HOT CHOCOLATE - MARTEN END

var app = builder.Build();

var hstsAge = builder.Configuration["Hsts:MaxAge"] ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Hsts:MaxAge was not provided");
app.UseHsts(options => options.MaxAge(days: int.Parse(hstsAge)).IncludeSubdomains());

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseMiddleware<XContentTypeOptionsMiddleware>();

app.UseSecurityHeaders(
    new HeaderPolicyCollection()
        .AddDefaultSecurityHeaders()
        .AddCustomHeader("X-Xss-Protection", "1; mode=block")
);

app.UseCors(corsPolicy); // todo: kind of redundant due of the next line?
app.UseReferrerPolicy(opts => opts.StrictOrigin());

app.MapGraphQL();

if (args.Contains("codegen"))
{
    await app.RunOaktonCommands(args);
}
else
{
    app.RunWithGraphQLCommands(args);
}
```

And this is my configuration

```
"Cors": {
    "AllowOrigin":{
      "Origins": ["https://localhost:7131", "http://localhost:5152"],
      "Methods": ["GET"],
      "Headers": ["Content-Type"]
    }
  },
```

I expected this to block any POST request, since it only have GET as allowed...
But when I go to https://localhost:7131/graphql/ I can make POST requests that are returning 200 without any problem.

Why is Post not being blocked?

Btw I have this in the logs:

```
[14:17:19 INF] CORS policy execution successful.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do browsers block POST requests if POST isn’t in the Access-Control-Allow-Methods value of the preflight OPTIONS response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71409753/do-browsers-block-post-requests-if-post-isn-t-in-the-access-control-allow-method)